# How to Create a New Participant Profile

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, profile

I want to create a new Participants Profile which includes Participant custom fields. How can I do that ?

The only way I see is by copying/renaming the "reserved" Participant Status Profile, and adding my custom fields ; but I can't remove the Participant Status field from it, nor disable the original "reserved" Participant Status Profile.

So, when I want to multiple update (Action) some selected participants of an Event Search, I have the choice between those 2 Profiles which both contain the same Participant Status field (which is confusing).

As an alternative, how can I remove the "Participant Status" profile from this choice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"When you create a profile, it is the fields that you select that determine what the profile type is"

Thank you Tamar, I did not realize that

Comment: Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to go to Admin > Customise > Profiles, then Add Profile, then add some Participant fields

There is a short lived example here http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/uf/group/field?reset=1&action=browse&gid=16

Comment: Hi Pete, that's OK to create a new "Contact type" Profile, but it won't appear as a choice for a "Multi-select action" related to a Participants selection : to have it appearing, I need it to be a Participant type Profile (BTW, your link seems to be broken)

Comment: The demo site gets refreshed everyday. It might help people help you if you can go set up a similar profile on the Demo site and then share that here. Others may understand your requirement but I don't, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a profile, it is the fields that you select that determine what the profile type is - you mention that you have custom data that you want to update, the custom data set must be designated for use for participants - all fields in the profile must be of type participant for the profile to be available for updating multiple participants.

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to make changes to reserved profiles since they are most likely in use by the code for certain "under the hood" actions that the system performs, but if you have a developer on hand, they should be able to disable it under the hood if they deem that it does not affect anything that you need for your daily operations.

Alternatively, you could create a completely new profile and call it "Update Participants" so that it is easier to differentiate from the reserved Participant Status profile.

Hope this helps,
Tamar

Comment: I don't want to modify the existing reserved Participant Profile ; but if I create a new "Update Participant" Profile, it can only be a Contact Profile, not a Participant Profile ; thus, it won't appear in the multi-select action of a participants selection. I need this new profile to be a Participant one : how can I do that ?